# Mongodb collection replication and read cursors

Tags: mongodb, replication, isolation-level

I want to replicate a collection from mongodb into some other data sink. One approach is to get the last oplog entry timestamp, record it, then do a find on the entire collection and iterate over that cursor sending documents to the sink. Once that cursor is exhausted, I read the oplog operations since the timestamp I got at the beginning. (something like what [mongo-connector](https://github.com/yougov/mongo-connector) does)
In pseudo code:

```
lastTs = getLatestOplogTimestamp(); -> t1
doDumpOfCollection(collectionName);
streamOperationsFromOlog(since=lastTs); - t2
```

Let's say during the time between t1 and t2, there were updates to collectionName whereby say an item was added to a subdocument array, or some other update that is stateful.

```
document1.items.append(item1);
```

The questions is:

1. Will/can that new data show up in the cursor iteration?
2. What would happen when I replay the oplog - can I have duplicate items in the array.

The [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/iterate-a-cursor/#cursor-isolation) suggests that other operations can be "interleaved" with the query which would suggest that the answer to both of these items is yes.

If so, is there a way to reliably replicate a single collection from mongo? It doesn't seem to me that something like Mongo Connector does it with strong data integrity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [snapshot reads](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/read-concern-snapshot/) are meant to address your requirements.